# How to optimize an update SQL in Oracle which update a particular row continuously

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for POS. After each transaction I need to update POS balance. But when I execute update SQL for a particular POS frequently, then update statements takes long time. Can you suggest how can I reduce update time?

I have already used /*+  parallel (auto) */ but no progress!

```
update pos_station
set balance = balance - #balance#
where posid = #posId#
```

`posid` is primary key of `pos_station` table.

Here is my Table details in picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtCLI.png)

Comment: Post the table details. It could be that there is no index on posid, and that is what causes the long query. Would need more information to asses

Comment: How many record you have? How many updates per second you have? How often you have insert in this table? Did you check concurency over that update?

Comment: Mladen , I have few records, but i need to frequently update each row. After each financial transaction i need to update POS balance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you committing the changes after each update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "when I execute update SQL for a particular POS frequently, then update statements takes long time"

This doesn't sound like a performance issue but more like a poor transaction design. Multiple sessions attempting to update the same row will block each other. The first session to get a lock on the row will block all the others, causing them to hang. The "long time" is not the update itself nor the seek time to find the record: it's the waiting to get a lock to apply the update. Parallel processing would not improve this situation.

As for solutions, the specifics depend on your application architecture. It might be appropriate to queue balance updates and apply them in a background process. It might be appropriate to introduce a pessimistic locking strategy using SELECT … FOR UPDATE syntax. Maybe you need to redesign your transactions, with smaller units of work so that you COMMIT more frequently, which would mean the update holds the lock for a smaller amount of time. Unfortunately your question lacks sufficient detail for us to offer a concrete suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
update pos_station
    set balance = balance - #balance#
    where posid = #posId#;
```

You want an index on `pos_status(posid)`.

Comment: in pos_station table, posid is primary key.